# Debug assertion in MFC in VS2012

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012

I'm migrating a legacy GUI application to VS2012. When running this application in debug mode, I'm getting a debug assertion when I try to instantiate a toolbar with the following line of code:

```
if(!m_wndMain.Create(this) || !m_wndMain.LoadToolBar(IDR_MAIN))
```

After digging around in MFC code, I found that the following line has changed in bartool.cpp has changed in MSVC10->11 from:

```
if (lpBitmap == NULL)
```

to:

```
if ((lpBitmap == NULL) || (lpBitmap->biBitCount > 8))
```

in AfxLoadSysColorBitmap.
In my case `lpBitmap->biBitCount` = 24 which causes `AfxLoadSysColorBitmap` to return `NULL` which in turn causes the debug assertion.
Any ideas on how to rectify my program's behavior to avoid this debug assertion?

Comment: [Here's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/bc6d565e-23f7-42fb-abe5-98b41daf4051) someone describing what seems to be a related problem. Read the answer by Cezary H. Noweta towards the bottom of the page, maybe that'll help you.

Comment: @Cezary: The problems do seem to be related. However, the call to LoadBitmap is being done in bartool.cpp in CToolBar::LoadToolBar so I have no way to use CBitmap's variation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from changing the bitmap to be 8-bit (256 colors) your best option is to use CMFCToolBar instead. This supports higher bit-depth bitmaps (including 24 and 32 bit) bitmaps.

Comment: thanks. Down-scaling the images worked like a charm. However, this begs the question: how come this worked in VS2010? Not only did the toolbar loaded there, but the images were visible as well. Only explanation I can see is that MFC down-scaled the images to 8 bit...

Answer (score 0):

elad please check that the bitmap images you are using are indeed only 8 bit.
i think you are using 24 bit images. hence the error.

try to convert them into 8 bit , bitmaps